# Does the order of OrderBy, Select and Where clauses in Linq-to-entities matter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Suppose I have a table of students with tons of columns. I want to the EF equivalent of

```
SELECT id,lastname,firstname 
FROM students 
WHERE coursename='Eurasian Nomads'
ORDER BY lastname,firstname
```

I just want a subset of the full `Student` model so I made a view model

```
public class StudentView{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
}
```

and this EF code seems to work:

```
List<StudentView> students=context.Students
.Where(s=>s.CourseName=="Eurasian Nomads")
.OrderBy(s=>s.LastName)
.ThenBy(s=>s.FirstName)
.Select(s=>new StudentView(){ID=s.ID,LastName=s.LastName,FirstName=s.FirstName})
.ToList();
```

But my question is does the order of these clauses matter at all, and if so, what sort of rules should I follow for best performance?

For example, this also seems to work:

```
List<StudentView> students=context.Students
.Select(s=>new StudentView(){ID=s.ID,LastName=s.LastName,FirstName=s.FirstName})
.OrderBy(s=>s.LastName)
.ThenBy(s=>s.FirstName)
.Where(s=>s.CourseName=="Eurasian Nomads")
.ToList();
```

Comment: I'll let someone post a full fledged answer, but no the order does not matter because all of the methods return an `IQueryable` object and the execution of the query is actually deferred to the last moment possible, in your case when you `ToList`

Comment: If you are using SQL server then you can use SQL Profiler to see what SQL query does each variation produce and the time each one takes. If I had to guess I would say that they are the same.

Comment: `Select` matters because it changes your `IQueryable` type from one form to another. `OrderBy` and `Where` should not matter.

Comment: Here specifically order doesn't appear to matter much, but in the general sense, certainly order can make a difference in linq-to-entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which you create your query before it's executed against the server is not relevant in most cases.

Actually one of the advantages is to be able of gradually create the query by concatenating where, order by, and other clauses.

But there are sometimes where the order can affect the generated sql.

Take the samples you provided. They both compile correctly, but the second does not actually get executed. If you try to run this query against an EF database you will get an **NotSupportedException**:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'CourseName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

The key here is that you are trying to filter the query by the CourseName property in the view model (StudentView) and not the property of the entity. 
So you get this error.

In the case of the first query, it correctly generates this sql:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName],
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName]
    FROM [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE N'Eurasian Nomads' = [Extent1].[CourseName]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[LastName] ASC, [Extent1].[FirstName] ASC
```

So, as you can see the order is critical sometimes.

Comment: This is a great explanation. I think it's worth adding that the `NotSupportedException` is because the `Select` is turning the query into a `StudentView` query, not a `Student` query, and `StudentView` doesn't contain a property for `CourseName`.

Comment: Indeed @Max. That is what I meant when I said "The key here is that you are trying to filter the query by the CourseName property in the view model" but I think your clarification is certainly valid. Thanks.